# How to collect data from multiple sheets by using sheet names

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for the response!

however the code which you sent started from the beginning of the workbook. but it should not be.

For example, a workbook contains sheets (only user knows the sheet name, so we can't give the sheet name on the code) as following

Summary/Version/AA/BB/CC/DD/Final

If beginsheet=AA then the code should start collecting data from AA and if endsheet = DD then the code should stop collecting data at Final. Only till DD is valid.

So how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a FOR - EACH: `For each theSheets in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets`

```
For each theSheets in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheets(theSheets.Name).Select
    msgbox(theSheets.Name)
next
```

I put the MSGBOX just to show the name of the sheet. Also the Select is not necessary I put it there just to show how it changes from sheet to sheet.

If you don't want to search all sheets (each sheet) but a specified number of sheets, you can assign the sheets names to a collection and the iterate that collection; in that case you have to know the names of the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I did not get your first question... 
Well, I don't know how practical this solution will be for you purpose but you could do the following:

1. When you open the workbook create CheckBoxes with the names of the Sheets:

   `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim row As Integer
   row = 14
   For Each mysheets In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(20, row, 50, 20).Select
            With Selection
               .Caption = mysheets.Name
               .Value = xlOff
               .LinkedCell = "C" & ToRow
               .Display3DShading = False
           End With
   row = row + 50
   Next
   End Sub`
2. Have the users select the Sheets that apply.
3. Fill a collection with the "Text" of the selected CheckBoxes (which will be the names of the sheets)
4. Iterate through the sheets in the collection

   Dim allSelectedSheets As New Collection
       Public Sub FindSelectedCkBox()

   ```
       For Each ckbox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
           If ckbox.Value > 0 Then
               allSelectedSheets.Add ckbox.Text
           End If
       Next
       iterateThroughSheets
   End Sub
   ```

   Sub iterateThroughSheets()
               For Each theSheets In allSelectedSheets
                   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(theSheets).Select
               Next
           End Sub

Make sure to remove the CheckBoxes when opening the Book so you don't end up with duplicates.